# Which class is most suited to read and represent a HTML file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

It is a beginner question. The platform and number of classes in Foundation Class is simply overwhelming to comb through, so I hope the SO community has a ready answer to offer.

This is my use case:

*I want to read in a html file and extract all the text in **p** tag.*

I do not need to display the html markup. But if Webkit has a solution I am happy to use it.

In python world, the answer will be Beautiful Soup. I am looking for OSX foundation kit equivalent or whatever classes that may achieve the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NSXMLDocument` and pass in the `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` as one of the `mask` options.
This will allow `NSXMLDocument` to parse non-XHTML documents (if they aren't completely malformed).

To get a node list of all p elements, you can use the following XPath expression on your `NSXMLDocument` instance:
        NSArray* pNodes = [projectDocument nodesForXPath:@"//*/@p" error:nil];

To get the text content of your p nodes, use the stringValue property.